# AEM 6.5 how to Add System user to workflow-administrator group

Tags: workflow, aem

I'm trying to complete a workitem programatically via workflow session using a System User but i'm getting error to add system user to workflow-administrator group, Any idea how to add System user to Workflow-administrator group

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: System user not a member of workflow-administrator group

Comment: Can you share a screen capture? Are you trying to do this via the /useradmin interface?